# String returned from MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I try to retrieve values from a MySQL database with this Python script:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

config_file = {}
try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(<removed.)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exists")
  else:
    print(err)
else:

  cursor = cnx.cursor()

  cursor.execute("SELECT config_key, config_value FROM T_ConfigTable")

  for (config_key, config_value) in cursor:
    print("{}: {}".format( config_key, config_value))
    config_file[config_key] = config_value

  cursor.close

  cnx.close

  print( config_file)
```

But the result always comes back as:

b'value1': b'value2'

etc

How can I get rid of the b's?

I use Python 3.2

thanks for your help

Comment: use `srt(config_value)` to get the string value

Comment: This doesn't help. Same result.

Comment: Yes it is. I know I should have mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `config_value.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

See this question for more detail on single/double letters preceding strings: [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

If you are using Python 2.x, the `b` will be ignored and it is simply treated as a string. If you are using Python 3.x, the `b` prefix means it's currently in byte format.

Assuming you're using Python 2.x, simply cast the config_value to a string: `print str(config_value)`

Comment: I actually did read this. But I'm still unclear on how to solve the issue.

Comment: You mean it doesn't work or you don't understand what I'm suggesting?

Comment: The str() function doesn't help - as far as I understand because I use Python3. And the other thread you mentioned I basically understood but don't know how to apply to solve the problem.

Comment: Any other ideas for Python3?